# How to get a single row from the duplicate rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to get only 1 row from the number of duplicate aspect_id(rows) returned.

```
SELECT rt.taxonomy_id,rt.iteration,ra.* FROM request_taxonomy rt 
inner join request_aspects ra ON ra.aspect_id = rt.request_aspects_id
                WHERE rt.requests_id = 6 and ra.section_name='Timeline';
```

Is there any way to get the distinct rows based on aspect_id?

Comment: `GROUP BY` can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GROUP BY:

```
SELECT 
    rt.taxonomy_id,rt.iteration,ra.* 
FROM request_taxonomy rt 
        inner join request_aspects ra ON ra.aspect_id = rt.request_aspects_id
WHERE rt.requests_id = 6 and ra.section_name='Timeline'
GROUP BY aspect_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY` can help you

```
SELECT rt.taxonomy_id,rt.iteration,ra.* 
FROM request_taxonomy rt 
inner join request_aspects ra ON ra.aspect_id = rt.request_aspects_id
WHERE rt.requests_id = 6 and ra.section_name='Timeline' 
GROUP BY aspect_id;
```